# Is it possible to define the order of initialization of portlets on start of portal?

Tags: dependencies, liferay, portlet, startup

I would like to specify the order of initialization of portlets when the portal server starts.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the order of deployment over the definition of portlet dependency. Set the `required-deployment-contexts=MyPrevPortlet` in `liferay-plugin-package.properties`.

Comment: I didn't see that the question was also asked by You :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible.

You can specify the order of deployment of the plugins by setting the `required-deployment-contexts` property in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` of the dependent portlet.

**Examples:**

If your portlet `my-custom-portlet` depends on other plugins then you can specify as follows:

1) For single dependency `required-deployment-contexts`:

```
required-deployment-contexts=my1-other-portlet
```

2) For multiple `required-deployment-contexts`:

```
required-deployment-contexts=\
    my-other-theme,\
    my1-other-portlet,\
    my-other-hook,\
    my2-other-portlet
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but in one portlet projects if more than one portlet exists then if one portlet is dependent on other one.. like one portlet add some value in session and based on session second one portlet have to dsiplay data then how can we set an order of portlet??

Comment: session sharing is run-time and not deployment time. So I don't think it has anything to do with which portlet is deployed first.