# liferay use custom portlet`s service in other portlet

Tags: liferay-6

I have created portlet (first-portlet) that has a service layer.i want to access this service from other portlet(second-portlet).

i dont want to recreate service in second-portlet.

**service.xml**  created in first-portlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.0.0//EN"     "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="com.test.habib">
<author>Habib</author>
<namespace>habib</namespace>

<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true">

    <!-- PK fields -->

    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />

    <!-- Audit fields -->

    <column name="companyId" type="long" />
    <column name="userId" type="long" />
    <column name="createDate" type="Date" />
    <column name="modifiedDate" type="Date" />

    <!-- Other fields -->

    <column name="title" type="String" />
    <column name="author" type="String" />

            <!-- Order -->

    <order by="asc">
        <order-column name="title" />
    </order>

    <!-- Finder methods -->

    <finder name="Title" return-type="Collection">
        <finder-column name="title" />
    </finder>
</entity>
</service-builder>
```

I copyed the first-portlet-service.jar to docroot/WEB-INF/lib/ of second-portlet.
and
use service in second-portlet:

**view.jsp**

```
<%@page import="com.test.habib.service.BookLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.test.habib.model.Book"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>SecondPortlet</b> portlet in View mode.

<%

List<Book> b = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(-1, -1);

for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
out.println(b.get(i).getAuthor()+"  , "+b.get(i).getTitle());
}

%>
```

**error**

```
 08:56:59,256 ERROR [PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:137] org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /html/jsps/view.jsp at line 31

28: 
29: 
30: 
31: List<Book> b = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(-1, -1);
32: 
33: for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
34:     out.println(b.get(i).getAuthor()+"  , "+b.get(i).getTitle());


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /html/jsps/view.jsp at line 31

28: 
29: 
30: 
31: List<Book> b = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(-1, -1);
32: 
33: for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++){
34:     out.println(b.get(i).getAuthor()+"  , "+b.get(i).getTitle());


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:316)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:134)
    at com.second.SecondPortlet.include(SecondPortlet.java:40)
    at com.second.SecondPortlet.doView(SecondPortlet.java:25)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:101)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:638)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:723)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:425)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3740)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:3699)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1168)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.RenderPortletAction.execute(RenderPortletAction.java:85)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.UpdateLayoutAction.addPortlet(UpdateLayoutAction.java:260)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.UpdateLayoutAction.execute(UpdateLayoutAction.java:211)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:153)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:508)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:485)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:261)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.themepreview.ThemePreviewFilter.processFilter(ThemePreviewFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:110)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:182)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:81)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:179)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter.processFilter(ThreadLocalFilter.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.habib.service.BookLocalServiceClp.<init>(BookLocalServiceClp.java:390)
    at com.test.habib.service.BookLocalServiceUtil.getService(BookLocalServiceUtil.java:240)
    at com.test.habib.service.BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(BookLocalServiceUtil.java:185)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.jsps.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 125 more
```

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178948/is-it-possible-to-define-the-order-of-initialization-of-portlets-on-start-of-por

Comment: thank you @nagenda. i tested it but the same error was occured.